# UWP - the order will be wrong on GridView when the column counts be changed

Tags: gridview, uwp, itemtemplate, reorderlist

I encounter a problem that the order will be wrong on Gridview when the column count be changed.
Could someone help to solve, please?
[image]

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="DragDropTestApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:DragDropTestApp"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>

        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Update" />
        <GridView
            x:Name="grid"
            Margin="100,10,0,10"
            AllowDrop="True"
            CanDragItems="True"
            CanReorderItems="True"
            IsSwipeEnabled="True"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.PreviewItems}">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid
                        Width="340"
                        Height="240"
                        Padding="5,0,5,0"
                        BorderThickness="1">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="180" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <ContentPresenter
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            Content="{Binding ImageThumbnail}" />
                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Name="clu">
                    <WrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="5" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public ObservableCollection<PreviewItem> PreviewItems = new ObservableCollection<PreviewItem>();
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                var item = new PreviewItem();
                item.ImageThumbnail = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image();
                ImageSource result = new BitmapImage(new Uri($"ms-appx:///Assets/{i + 1}.png"));
                item.ImageThumbnail.Source = result;

                PreviewItems.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

PreviewItem.cs

```
public class PreviewItem : ObservableObject
{
    private Image _imageThumbnail;
    public Image ImageThumbnail { get => _imageThumbnail; set => SetProperty(ref _imageThumbnail, value); }
  

    public PreviewItem()
    {
        
    }     
   
}
```

Here is my project and cord. https://github.com/houzhiwei/UWPProject

Thanks

Zack

I develop a page list on gridview and hope it work normal.

Comment: I used your project, and it didn't crash, everything worked fine. Maybe you can provide your windows system version and other information. https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYnzb.gif

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the GridView's default virtualization behavior, which reuses the containers of the items when the item is scrolled out of view.

If you don't want this behavior, it is recommended that you replace `WrapGrid` with `ItemsWrapGrid` and set [CacheLength="0"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemswrapgrid.cachelength?view=winrt-22621) to disable GridView virtualization.

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Name="clu">
        <ItemsWrapGrid CacheLength="0" MaximumRowsOrColumns="5" Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
If I replace WrapGrid with ItemsWrapGrid,  the app will be crashed when I swap the items.

Comment: I modified WrapGrid based on your code and it didn't crash when I swap the items. Could you please describe it in detail?

Comment: The crash is that I swap the items to reorder the griditem after replace WrapGrid with ItemsWrapGrid. Just like this post 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72867096/uwp-drag-and-drop-with-canreorderitems-true-in-gridview-app-will-crash-tha

Comment: I used your project and it didn't crash. Everything worked fine. Maybe you can provide your windows system version and other information. https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYnzb.gif

Comment: I run app on Windows 10 or Windows 11, it will be crashed. 
System version:
版本 Windows 11 企業版
版本 22H2
安裝於 ‎2023/‎8/‎25
OS 組建 22621.2134
序號 PC1NG72T
體驗 Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22659.1000.0

Comment: You can try to update your Windows to OS Build 22621.2283. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/september-12-2023-kb5030219-os-build-22621-2283-8b9ba74f-fdde-4c75-b049-77cf214f4a66

Comment: I update windows OS to 22621.2283. it will still crash.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of the crash or error message? I tested it on other Windows device and it didn't crash. Maybe you can try testing your app on other devices.

Comment: This is error message.
https://imgur.com/61nSRbE
https://imgur.com/h28GmII